# Choose Printer Tray automatically From Excel VBA to print Word Document

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to print Word Document From Excel
I want to choose printer tray to print word document in default printer. 
First 2 pages in Tray one (Letter Heads) and 3rd to 5th page in Tray Two (A4 Sheets) Using excel VBA.

Below code is working fine to print in default printer and tray.
Help me to Choose Trays

```
'Print in letter head:- Choose Tray one
```

and

```
'Print Other pages in A4:- Choose Tray Two
```

Printer details:

*Network Printer
*Hp Laser printer 5200 dtn

```
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, ans As String, i As Integer
            Dim objWord As Object
            Dim intpage As Integer, intcopies As Integer, intnrml As Integer

            Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            objWord.Visible = True

            ' path to the folder
            directory = "C:\Users\bharath.a.raj.DIR\Desktop\Print\"
            fileName = Dir(directory & "*.doc*") ' Open Multiple Word Docs Both .doc and .docx
            Do While fileName <> ""
            objWord.Documents.Open (directory & fileName)

            On Error Resume Next
           '
            intcopies = CInt(InputBox("How many copies?"))
            intpage = 1 'Letter head page no.
            intnrml = 3 'A4 page no.
            On Error GoTo 0

            If intpage * intcopies <> 0 Then
                For i = 1 To intcopies ' Loop to print next page of uer Choice Note: simplex is not working in my Office, Default Duplex
                    'Network Printer :- HP Laser Printer 5200dtn
                    'Print in letter head:- Choose Tray one
                    objWord.PrintOut Range:=4, Pages:=CStr(intpage) '1st page
                    intpage = intpage + 1
                    objWord.PrintOut Range:=4, Pages:=CStr(intpage) '2nd page
                    intpage = 1
                    'Print Other pages in A4:- Choose Tray Two
                    objWord.PrintOut Range:=4, Pages:=CStr(intnrml) '3rd page
                    intnrml = intnrml + 1
                    objWord.PrintOut Range:=4, Pages:=CStr(intnrml) '4th page
                    intnrml = intnrml + 1
                    objWord.PrintOut Range:=4, Pages:=CStr(intnrml) '5th page
                    intnrml = 3

                Next
            Else
                MsgBox "sorry, wrong page or copies, try again"
            End If
               ' Next
            objWord.Documents.Close
                ' set file to next in Dir
            fileName = Dir()
            Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

We use a really great utility called Tray Selector which you can download from http://us.trayselector.com and try for free. You can set up one click buttons to print to any printer and tray combination and even call these buttons using VBA macros. It's been very useful in our law firm.